# QButtonGroup not making checkboxes exclusive

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qbuttongroup

I am attempting to make a set of exclusive checkboxes, using QGroupBox (which, as I understand it, is exclusive by default), but when I run my program, the checkboxes are not exclusive and behave as they normally would.

```
skillP = QCheckBox("Passive")
skillCb = QCheckBox("Combat")
skillCm = QCheckBox("Command")
skillP.setChecked(True)
addskillG = QButtonGroup()
addskillG.addButton(skillP)
addskillG.addButton(skillCm)
addskillG.addButton(skillCb)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried your code and I see that there are no problems, you could show more code, maybe what the error is in another part of your code

Comment: this is my test: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/ece0fe6e0f719267fda6cc7775568615

Comment: There's not much else, but okay:

`layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(skillP, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(skillCb, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(skillCm, 1, 3)` I don't see how that would change anything, though.

Comment: Have you tried the test I proposed?

Comment: Yes, I have. It worked when executed on its own, but my code segment still does not work properly.

Comment: In order to test you could share your code through github, drive or similar.

Comment: Alright, here is my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c8d64ce87233bdf0fc940f66cd0e077d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused because the garbage collector removes from the memory the variable QButtonGroup, to solve that problems you must pass a parent to this object:

```
addskillG = QButtonGroup(self)
```